# How to get HMODULE from COM GUID

Tags: c++, winapi, com

I need HMODULE to call GetModuleInformation but I only know COM GUID of class that reside in dll. Is there winapi function to determine HMODULE (or dll name) knowing only GUID?

EDIT: Application running as normal user (not elevated)

Comment: [GetModuleHandleEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683200.aspx), passing the address of an interface method.

Comment: @IInspectable: that will only work for in-process COM objects, and even then only if you actually have an instance of the COM object.  The OP says he only has a GUID, not an object.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: *"that will only work for in-process COM objects"* - Since `HMODULE`s are only meaningful in-process, I don't think this limits the scope of applicability. And you don't need an instance of an object to get the address of a member function either. The type information is enough, and a GUID uniquely identifies a type.

Comment: @IInspectable A GUID is just an ID number, it does not directly point to any type, so you need to perform a lookup to find the actual type. And yes, you do need an object instance in this case. The COM interface type is an abstract class, it has no memory addresses of its own. You would need direct access to the class type that implements the COM interface in order to get a memory address of any of the class methods. COM hides that access, so you won't be able to get any implementation memory address without an actual object instance so you can analyze the addresses in its vtable.

Comment: @RemyLebeau: I took *"I only know COM GUID of class that reside in dll"* to mean, that the GUID identifies a COM **object** in this case, not an interface. In that case there is a direct mapping between a GUID and a type (or v-table if you wish). No instance required for the lookup.

Comment: @IInspectable: Types are only known at compile-time. A GUID known at runtime must be manually resolved to a type. So yes, a lookup is required. And COM does not provide that lookup, you have to implement it yourself. And again, an instance is required if you intend to lookup memory addresses of implemented interface methods.

Comment: Plus, even from an interface pointer I'm not sure you *can* get the address of one of the methods, other than by manually hacking into the vtable (such as by using the `CINTERFACE` declaration): Last time I tested in Visual Studio, taking the address of a virtual function as a pointer-to-member seemed to return the address of a static wrapper that called the function virtually...

Answer (score 2):

If the GUID is a CLSID for a COM object, you can lookup the object's implementing EXE/DLL filename in the Windows Registry (in the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\CLSID\{guid}` subkey), or if your app is using Registration-Free COM, in the app's SxS manifest instead.

If the object is in a DLL, you can then use `GetModuleHandle/Ex()` if that DLL has already been loaded in your process's memory, or `LoadLibrary()` to load it into memory.

Comment: That won't work for [registration-free COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973913.aspx).

Comment: Registration-Free COM uses a manifest, so you could just lookup the GUID in the manifest instead of the Registry.  The manifest will have the path to the COM object's EXE/DLL file.

Comment: I perfectly understand, how registration-free COM is implemented. I was pointing out, that your answer isn't applicable for this common scenario.

Comment: Won't work for a surrogate or an out-of-process server or DCOM either.  It is forbidden knowledge.